# drag item count w/jQuery

Tags: jquery-ui

I am trying to write a progress indicator code to show how much of a task is complete. I am trying to use jQuery UI's drag and drop functionality. The items that need to be moved are on the left. When they are dragged withing a plot area on the right the counter needs to update on drop. It only needs to count the number of items moved and not how many times each item is moved withing the grid area $("#grid").

I think I am close but not quite there yet. Here's what I've got so far:

```
var startCount = $("#launchPad .card").length;
var moveFromLaunch = false;

$(".card").bind( "dragstart", function(event, ui) {
    moveFromLaunch = true;
});

$("#dropZone").bind( "drop", function(event, ui) {
    var currentCount = $("#launchPad .card").length;
    if (moveFromLaunch)
        currentCount--;
    currentCount = startCount - currentCount;
    moveFromLaunch = false;
    var progress = Math.floor(currentCount / startCount * 100);
    $("#progBarRd").width(progress);
    $('#progBar').attr("title", progress+'%');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have any code that will cause #launchPad to decrease in element size. The .card will move position, no DOM element parent.

Try tagging the items you drop and counting the number of dropped items which have no tag set yet (use a class and the jQuery CSS selectors).

Good luck!

Comment: What do you mean? I use $("#launchPad .card").length; to count remaining items inside #launchPad...